# Convert .csv.gz to GeoJSON with R

Tags: r, geojson

I am trying to read the file from this link in R(Microsoft Office building footprint). It is supposed to be a geojson file.

https://minedbuildings.blob.core.windows.net/global-buildings/2023-06-27/global-buildings.geojsonl/RegionName%3DNetherlands/quadkey%3D120200313/part-00138-7b73ad6b-e7c8-4e22-9fa2-01d140ca911d.c000.csv.gz

After unzipping the file, I get a csv. How do I read this file in R.

There's python code to read the file but I am not able to replicated this in R.
https://github.com/microsoft/GlobalMLBuildingFootprints/blob/main/scripts/make-gis-friendly.py

Comment: hi 89_Simple! Just reading through the github link you posted, I think it's a guide on how to ***convert*** it into GeoJSON, it's not saying it is already in that format

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Yes I am aware. The python code can convert it into GeoJSON. It's just that I don't know how to translate that into R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out GeoJSON files are (fortunately) very easy to read and understand, and the csv file you have is basically all of the child elements of the GeoJSON file, without the wrapping. So we provide that wrapping, and everything works out fine:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, leaflet)

file_path = "part-00138-7b73ad6b-e7c8-4e22-9fa2-01d140ca911d.c000.csv"

# in an excellent turn of events, it turns out geojson files are easy to read
readLines(file_path) %>% 
 paste(collapse = ", ") %>%
 {paste0('{"type": "FeatureCollection",
           "features": [', ., "]}")} -> j

# plot the map
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addGeoJSON(j) %>%
  setView(lng = 5.366252941303844, lat = 53.40141145330422, zoom = 11)
```

[image: map of netherlands]
Credit: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#Example) (for providing a good example of GeoJSON for me!)

Comment: Great. I was looking for this. I did one more step `geojson::to_geojson(j)` to convert into class `geojson`.